# Synchronization issue while updating element in ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have this code, where I am trying to update item(which is a list) in my concurrent dictionary for a key (key is same all the time).

Here is my code -:

```
class Program
    {
        private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<int>> s_mapDatatypeToSource = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<int>>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


                try
                {
                    Parallel.For(0, 10000000, i => AddItemToList(i, "local"));
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Exception thrown ...{0}", exception.Message));
                    Console.ReadLine();
                    throw;
                }

            Console.WriteLine("Completed without exception");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static void AddItemToList(int dataKey, string sourceName)
        {
            s_mapDatatypeToSource.AddOrUpdate(sourceName.ToUpperInvariant(), new List<int> { dataKey }, (s, list) =>
            {

                {
                    list.Add(dataKey);
                    return list;
                }


            });

        }
    }
```

one out of 10 times above code is throwing exception - "Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds."

I know this is a synchronization issue of list , but I am not getting why is this coming , since ConcurrentDictionary is thread safe. so I assume, it lets only one thread to update my list at one time, so there should not be any problem-:

I know I am missing something - suggestions please -:

Comment: please well format your code it is not readable

Comment: GetOrAdd and AddOrUpdate are not atomic (Thread safe)The MSDN itself says:
Also, although all methods of ConcurrentDictionary are thread-safe, not all methods are atomic, specifically GetOrAdd and AddOrUpdate. The user delegate that is passed to these methods is invoked outside of the dictionary's internal lock. (This is done to prevent unknown code from blocking all threads.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ConcurrentDictionary can be thread-safe, but List is not.

Look at decompiled method from List:

```
public void Add(T item)
{
  if (this._size == this._items.Length)
    this.EnsureCapacity(this._size + 1);
  this._items[this._size++] = item;
  ++this._version;
}
```

Thread #1 and Thead #2 can pass `if (this._size == this._items.Length)` at the same time. Thread #1 will set value here `this._items[this._size++] = item;`, but Thread #2 will cause IndexOutOfRangeException. You need thread-safe list.

**update** You can use [SynchronizedCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms668265%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead of List